# Build Definition: Copying the build output to the server?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops

When configuration the build definition, I have the option of copying the build output to the server:

[image: Build Defaults]

We are using the VSO Host Build Controller and Azure's Continuous Integration build template to release to our development environment after every check-in.

Is there any reason why we need to have this value set?  How could it ever be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Copy build output to the server** will put the output of the build as a zip file attached the build that can be downloaded later.

In a situation where you don't care about the build output because you have it setup to continuously deploy to Azure (or some other build based deployment) you would not use this option.

If you however needed to download the output, for example a Windows Store App that you need to publish to the Store manually, then you could use this to get the application.

In VSO you most likely don't have a Drop Server (unless you have invested in Azure heavily) so you have 2 choices:

- Put them in source control. Only in TFVC, not Git. Also fills up your Repo with Large Files.
- Attach them to the build as a Zip.

The second scenario is exactly where you would use this.